# Override default colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is probably an easy question for `ggplot2` experts: I want to use my own colors rather than the default colors. How to achieve that?

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
df <- structure(list(start = c(0, 251, 1976, 5127, 5717, 6783), end = c(251, 
1976, 5127, 5717, 6783, 6830), minute = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), AOI = c("*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*"), AOI_col = c("blue", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), groups = structure(list(minute = 0L, .rows = structure(list(
    1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The colors I wish to plot are in column `AOI_col`. Here's the code so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df5, aes(x = start, xend = end, 
                y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI)))/10,
                yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI)))/10,
                color = AOI)) +
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53, labels = paste0(0:53, "min"), name = NULL) +
  labs(title = "Gaze activity Speaker C F01") +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank())
```

I've tried using `aes(fill = AOI_col)` and `scale_color_manual(values = AOI_col)` but to no avail. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a color adjustment in the geom_segment():

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = start, xend = end, 
                y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI)))/10,
                yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI)))/10)) +
  geom_segment(size = 2, color = df$AOI_col) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53, labels = paste0(0:53, "min"), name = NULL) +
  labs(title = "Gaze activity Speaker C F01") +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank())
```

Or again the complete example with the answer from @user438383:

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      start = c(0, 251, 1976, 5127, 5717, 6783),
      end = c(251,
              1976, 5127, 5717, 6783, 6830),
      minute = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
                 0L),
      AOI = c("*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*"),
      AOI_col = c("blue",
                  "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L),
    groups = structure(
      list(
        minute = 0L,
        .rows = structure(
          list(1:6),
          ptype = integer(0),
          class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr",
                    "list")
        )
      ),
      row.names = 1L,
      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
      .drop = TRUE
    ),
    class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,
       aes(
         x = start,
         xend = end,
         y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
         yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
         color = AOI
       )) +
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53,
                  labels = paste0(0:53, "min"),
                  name = NULL) +
  labs(title = "Gaze activity Speaker C F01") +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = unique(df$AOI_col))
```

Comment: The key is missing. How can that be reinstated?

Comment: Hey, I'd be grateful if you could let me know how to print also the key. If it works I might accept your answer.

Comment: sorry, the solution with the `+ scale_colour_manual(values = unique(df$AOI_col))` is needed for this, it seems. So, @user438383 had the solution.

Comment: No adding this does not produce the key.

Comment: I edited the answer. Now there is an complete example. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think the ideal thing to do is make `AOI_col` a factor and sort it alphabetically, then assign the colours to be the unique values of that column:

```
df5$AOI_col = factor(df5$AOI_col, levels = sort(unique(df$AOI_col)))

ggplot(df5, aes(x = start, xend = end, 
                y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI)))/10,
                yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI)))/10,
                color = AOI)) +
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53, labels = paste0(0:53, "min"), name = NULL) +
  labs(title = "Gaze activity Speaker C F01") +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = unique(df$AOI_col))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've noticed though that there is not a strict association between  `AOI` and `AOI_col`. How can that be guaranteed?

Comment: Ah yes - actually my answer was a bit lazy. I think what you would want to do is make ``AOI_col`` a factor with the levels sorted like ``factor(AOI_col, levels=sort(unique(AOI_col))``, which should ensure the colours are the in right order. I have tried some combinations and it always seems to work.

Comment: No it doesn't seem to work. It prints colors which I have not predefined in `df5$AOI_col`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann that's strange, it's produces the correct figure for me.

Comment: The problem is that the color assignment does not remain stable across different subsets of the data. So in one go, for example, one particular `AOI` is red, while in another go it is green. How can the color assignment be made stable?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann This is the right solution. I think there is some irritation with the dataframe name! It is `df` and the other time it is ´df5´

Comment: No, it plots red, green and black, whereas the colors defined in `AOI_col`are different ones.

Comment: I am still unsure what you mean by different 'subsets' of the data - could you share those? This example works ``df = data.frame(V1 = 1:20, V2 = rnorm(20), V3 = sample(c('green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'black', 'grey'), 20, replace=T)); df %>% dplyr::mutate(V3 = factor(V3, levels = sort(unique(V3)))) %>% ggplot(aes(x=V1, y=V2)) + geom_point(aes(colour=V3)) + scale_colour_manual(values = sort(unique(df$V3))``